# how to insert multiple rows using .set-or-append using KQL

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer, adx

[image: sample query]

I am trying to insert multiple rows using .set-or-append command in Kusto table. Will this command support multiple rows insertion?. If yes, how can i do that.

I want to insert 2 machines data named "IQVIA","GENE_S" at once using this .set command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `union` operator.

for example:

```
.set-or-append TargetTable <| 
    union
    (print x = "hello", y = "world", when = now()),
    (print x = "_foo_", y = "_bar_", when = ago(5m))
```

alternatively, you can create a file that includes all of the records you wish to ingest, then ingest that file.

- see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-overview